# Monitor will not stay in power-saving/standy state (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display, power-management, standby

When AFK the monitors enter standby after the power-plan monitor power off time but then immediately turn back on.

I've checked the event logs and couldn't see anything, including running the Windows troubleshooter and resetting the power profile.

It's a new installation of Windows 10 Pro (Jan 2018) with Steam, Adobe, Crashplan and a few small miscellaneous applications installed.

One helpful forum post indicated this as a resolution:

```
powercfg -requests
powercfg -requestsoverride driver “put driver name here” display
```

Looking at that, it seemed like a couple of VB-Audio drivers and a Realtek driver might be responsible. (Output  below).

I know the name of the .inf files related to VB-Audio via:

```
get-windowsdriver -online -all | out-string -stream | sls VB-Audio -Context 5,2
```

**Cmdline output :**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] VB-Audio Virtual Cable (ROOT\MEDIA\0000)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] VB-Audio Cable A (ROOT\MEDIA\0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] Realtek High Definition Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0900&SUBSYS_18491151&REV_1000\4&37605d4d&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller




PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsdriver -online -all | out-string -stream | sls VB-Audio -Context 5,3

  Driver           : oem13.inf
  OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vbmmecable64_win7.inf_amd64_ffa78ae84c13ca8c\vbmmecable64_win7.inf
  Inbox            : False
  ClassName        : MEDIA
  BootCritical     : False
> ProviderName     : VB-Audio Software
  Date             : 02/09/2014 00:00:00
  Version          : 1.0.3.5

  Driver           : oem14.inf
  OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vbmmecablea64_win7.inf_amd64_53772ecb56efb5ec\vbmmecablea64_win7.inf
  Inbox            : False
  ClassName        : MEDIA
  BootCritical     : False
> ProviderName     : VB-Audio Software
  Date             : 19/10/2015 00:00:00
  Version          : 1.0.3.5

  Driver           : oem15.inf
  OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vbvmvaio64_win7.inf_amd64_98635c590be27e38\vbvmvaio64_win7.inf
  Inbox            : False
  ClassName        : MEDIA
  BootCritical     : False
> ProviderName     : VB-Audio Software
  Date             : 21/04/2014 00:00:00
  Version          : 1.0.3.5

  Driver           : oem16.inf
  OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vbvmauxvaio64_win7.inf_amd64_eefc9c140807b56b\vbvmauxvaio64_win7.inf
  Inbox            : False
  ClassName        : MEDIA
  BootCritical     : False
> ProviderName     : VB-Audio Software
  Date             : 21/04/2014 00:00:00
  Version          : 1.0.3.5
```

Now I need to figure out what to put in "put driver name here" but don't know what's appropriate to enter into the powercfg commandlet. I have tried "oem22.inf" for the realtek driver, for example, no error was thrown but the situation has not improved and I'm not even sure that's the correct "driver name" to be using.

## EDIT 1

Ran the powecfg report, entries from the error section below:

```
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
Requesting Driver Instance  ROOT\MEDIA\0000
Requesting Driver Device    VB-Audio Virtual Cable
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
Requesting Driver Instance  ROOT\MEDIA\0001
Requesting Driver Device    VB-Audio Cable A
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
Requesting Driver Instance  HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0900&SUBSYS_18491151&REV_1000\4&37605d4d&0&0001
Requesting Driver Device    Realtek High Definition Audio
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
Driver Name \FileSystem\srvnet
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
A kernel component has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
```

All entries match up with what was seen from the powercfg requests, though they appear to be sleep preventing ones, not display level?

Am I in the right ballpark for diagnosing and remedying this, and does anyone know exactly what "Driver Name" in powercfg -requestsoverride should be?

## EDIT 2

On a whim I decided to disconnect my 2nd monitor, and to my surprise the standby activated correctly.  I reattached the monitor (Dell U2413) but did not connect the hub.  Standby works on both monitors.

Given that the hub had at that time only an empty card reader attached, and neither the hub nor card reader had "Allow this device to wake the machine" enabled (Nor appeared in any of the above diagnostics) how do I go about keeping the hub connected, without compromising the machine's ability to put the monitors into standby?